# No module names 'utils'. python3-utils already installed. Possible conflicts

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, import, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to import utils, but shows an import error. when trying to install, it says it already exists. 
Im using Ubuntu. Thank You

```
   mandala@mandala:~$ python3 test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import FIFOQueue
ImportError: No module named 'utils'

mandala@mandala:~$ sudo -H pip install python3-utils

Requirement already satisfied: python3-utils in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python3-utils)
```

EDIT:
I also tried installing pip3. now the utils should be installed in python3 directories?

```
mandala@mandala:~$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade python3-utils
Requirement already up-to-date: python3-utils in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from python3-utils)

You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

.

```
mandala@mandala:~$ python3 test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import FIFOQueue
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

EDIT 2:
I tried import [python3_utils], which the name of the folder in the dist-packages folder. but cannot import FIFOQueue. This is the link of what im trying to import.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-utils

```
mandala@mandala:~$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from python3_utils import FIFOQueue
ImportError: cannot import name 'FIFOQueue'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time but never know if it can help...

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install <your lib>
```

This should do the trick.